# I am having trouble multiple keywords separated by comma which can be used as a successful input in the function - does anyone have ideas?

Tags: r, shiny

This is UMAP function and by entering the colors names you can color the clusters but it is not working. It says that it sees only one color and 20 are needed. This is Seurat package.

This is the function that I used originally without shiny and it works

```
DimPlot(data, reduction = "umap", cols = c(colors[30], colors[1], colors[2], colors[28], colors[3], 
                                       colors[4], colors[5], "mistyrose", "lightpink4",  colors[21], "grey", colors[7], colors[9], colors[11], colors[24], colors[26], "magenta" ,"gold", "mistyrose2"), split.by = "orig.ident")
```

This code below if from the shiny app I am making

```
server <- function(input, output) {

col = renderText({ input$label.color })
cols <-  reactive({input$cols})

output$value <- renderText({ input$cols})

  output$tsneplot<-renderPlot({
    input$ts
    if (input$spl == "NULL") {
      isolate(DimPlot(data, seed = input$seed.use,reduction = "tsne",pt.size=input$pt.size, label = T, repel = T, label.size = input$label.size, cells = NULL, cols = NULL, label.color = "red"))
    } else {
      isolate(DimPlot(data, reduction = "tsne",pt.size= input$pt.size, split.by = input$spl ,cells = NULL, cols = c(cols()), label = T, label.size = input$label.size, label.color = col(), repel = T ))
    }
  })
  

}
```

I have seen the output value of text cols it shows exactly in the upper portion of the code below but for some reason while it is in the app and running the dimplot function it thinks it is only one string. Without the concept of shiny it works the code is tested but in the shiny platform it is not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du4RP.png)

Answer (score 0):

To examine what value `cols()` actually returns in your app, you can include a console-like output in your test version:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    ## ...
    verbatimTextOutput('log')
    ## ...
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ## ...
    output$log <- renderPrint(cols()) 
    ## ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that so its definitely showing like this. [1] "\"chondrocytes\", \"myoblasts,post-mitotic\", \"tenocytes\"" But then if I just write without quotes it makes it one word and there are commas like this "word, word, word". How can I make sure it is "word", "word", "word". I have searched everywhere but there is no solution

Comment: Thanks I solved the issue. I found that strpslit and dput work well.